# Microsoft Identity Platform 4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg/

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-identity-platform

When using [Microsoft Sample Code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg/Client)
"How to secure a Web API built with ASP.NET Core using the Microsoft identity platform (formerly Azure Active Directory for developers)"

I added 2 Scopes when following the registration steps (they suggest 1 scope but I added 1 additional) for the TodoList Service.
In the TodoListService there is a Task PrepareAuthenticatedClient()
[Link to code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg/Client/Services/TodoListService.cs)

```
private async Task PrepareAuthenticatedClient()
        {
            var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { _TodoListScope });
            Debug.WriteLine($"access token-{accessToken}");
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
```

I only add the default scope to the appsettings.json config that you are asked to register in the configuration section of the application when following the MS instructions but when the code runs and I get the access code and decode it using [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/)

I appear to have "scp": "access_as_editor access_as_user",

I would have thought I would only see access_as_user" as that is the scope that is passed in _TodoListScope. Should I see just 1 or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if you have granted consent to both scopes during application registration or by some other means, then what you are seeing is expected i.e. you should see both. The reason for this is due to how the [permissions and consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent) work in Azure AD. When you request an **Access Token** for a resource (such as your web API), all the scopes you have previously consented to *for that resource* will be returned, irrespective of whether you actually requested that scope at the time or not.

Comment: I thought that may have been the case but having it confirmed makes me feel much better.  I thought you may have been able to apply scopes as levels for who can do what (similar to the MS Graph scopes) Thanks for your answer

Comment: @GreyMatter oh that's still true, I didn't mean that user B will get all the scopes that the user A has consented before. It's just that user A will always get all the scopes that she previously consented to.